# document.write extremely slow except in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I need to open a new window and write on it some html/css. This the code that I'm using to accomplish that:

```
                myHTML = '...' //Around 400 bytes of html and styling
                var doc = window.open('', 'preview', 'width=1200,height=600,scrollbars=1');
                doc.document.write(myHTML);
                doc.focus();
                $(window).unload(function() {
                        doc.close();
                });
```

The issue that I'm having is that even though Firefox opens the new window and instantly writes/parses the html/css, showing it to the user with no delay, Chrome and Safari need around 5 seconds to show it.

Why is this happening? Any suggested workaround?

Comment: Can u post a fiddle with actual HTML data sample?

Comment: Perhaps `doc.document.close();` after your write?

Comment: `doc` is a confusing name for a window: please rename it to something else, such as `preview`.

Comment: I tried doc.document.close() but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: you're going to have to show a jsfiddle or some page showing this problem in action. I made a test page with this wrapped in a function that i call onclick and it displays '...' immediately.  Is the myHTML actually something else like js that's making and waiting for a request from something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments... I was gonna do a jsfiddle but the site was temporarily down... It is back now, but I solved the issue. The issue was this line in the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/templates/preview.css" />
```

For some reason, Chrome/Safari need some extra time to parse that. I changed it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.fulldomain.com/templates/preview.css" />
```

and everything works now.